# Log in password

Tags: auto-login

How to eliminate the login password requirement. My administrator had left the job and I am unable to login as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Ubuntu does not have a login for the user 'root'.

Instead you use `sudo command line` to run the command `command line`, and you *use your own user ID's password* to escalate the permissions and run with root permissions via `sudo`.

Example (to modify the file `/etc/fstab`),

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

So if you have the password for the previous administrator's user ID, fine. Otherwise you may need to reset that password,

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: In addition to what you said, you can also do `sudo bash` or `sudo -s` and that would give you a root shell :)

Comment: Yes, @marko, but it will defeat the purpose of `sudo`, to avoid running commands as root by mistake and create problems. Anyway,  in some special cases it is an advantage to run with a root shell via `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`. And we should remember to use `sudo -H gui-program` to run GUI application programs to avoid problems for the regular user ID with configuration files.